# Blender normal bake problem ("selected to active")

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, baking

So, I have several source parts and one model as the target. I want to bake one part at the time. The image is the outcome when I bake the biggest piece "selected to active". The outlined part is the outcome, which seems fine. But what is going with the rest of the map? None of these parts are right, not to mention they are not selected, and should not be baked at all. What is going on? I can't bake anything whatever order I chose.
[image]

Comment: Hard to say, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: "Selected" is selected object, not selected faces.  The whole object is baked, regardless of what has been selected in edit mode.  The weird looking places are likely places where the low poly intersects the high poly, leading to baking from the backside of the high poly rather than the intended side (which is closer, but in the wrong direction of low poly normals, so ignored.)